# Why do pseudoclasses on the host element have to be inside of the host function?

Tags: css, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I do not understand why pseudo classes like `:focus-within` need to be within the `:host()` function brackets when acting on the host itself. Why can it not be `:host:focus-within div`?
It's even more weird that it works on `:host` inside of another `:host()`.

```js
class MyElementFail extends HTMLElement {

 constructor(...args) {
  super(...args)

  this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `
  <style>
    :host{
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: salmon;
    }
    :host div{
      background-color: white;
    }
    /*This part is different:*/
  :host:focus-within div{
   background-color: green;
  }
  </style>
    <input type="text" value="click in here"/>
  <div>
    Change to green
  </div>`
 }
}
window.customElements.define('my-element-fail', MyElementFail);


class MyElement extends HTMLElement {

 constructor(...args) {
  super(...args)

  this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `
  <style>
    :host{
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: salmon;
    }
    :host div{
      background-color: white;
    }
    /*This part is different:*/
  :host(my-element:focus-within) div{
   background-color: green;
  }
  </style>
    <input type="text" value="click in here"/>
  <div>
    Change to green
  </div>`
 }
}
window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);


class MyElementTwo extends HTMLElement {

 constructor(...args) {
  super(...args)

  this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `
  <style>
    :host{
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: salmon;
    }
    :host div{
      background-color: white;
    }
    /*This part is different:*/
  :host(:host:focus-within) div{
   background-color: green;
  }
  </style>
    <input type="text" value="click in here"/>
  <div>
    Change to green
  </div>`
 }
}
window.customElements.define('my-element-two', MyElementTwo);
```

```html
No Good:
<my-element-fail></my-element-fail>
Good:
<my-element></my-element>
Good also:
<my-element-two></my-element-two>
```

Essentially, why does,

`:host(:host:focus-within) div{` work, and

`:host(my-element:focus-within) div{` work, but

`:host:focus-within div{` not work?

Comment: FYI: You should never use arguments in a Web Component constructor or in calling `super()` in the constructor: https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-element-conformance

Comment: @Intervalia Thanks. I learned to do this from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Polyfills_versus_classes

Comment: Well, that page was updated since 2019, but it was written like that before: https://github.com/mdn/content/blob/cbe151a06d6e5b4d1fbb46081bd16e69ef4c1630/files/en-us/web/web_components/using_custom_elements/index.html#L268

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:host` is only to indicate the host element of the shadowDOM.

`:host(.something)` indicated the host with a class of `.something`.

You can not use `:host.something` you must use the parenthesis.

**`:host()` is not a function. It is just how to select a `:host` with additional specificity.**

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `
  <style>
    :host{
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: salmon;
    }

    div{
      background-color: white;
    }

    :host(:focus-within) div{
   background-color: green;
  }
  </style>
    <input type="text" value="click in here"/>
  <div>Change to green</div>`;
 }
}
window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

Comment: I think this is a fairly good explanation, but the spec says that `:host()` ***is*** a function. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#host-selector

Comment: Not sure why they are using the word _function_ since it is basicly the same style as `:not()` https://devdocs.io/css/:not. CSS does have real functions like `calc() and `var()` but `:host()` is just a pseudo-class

Comment: Maybe they wanted to say *functional* rather than *function*

Comment: Maybe. Or maybe `:not()` is now considered a function and that is just the term to use when a pseudo-class uses parens. :)

Comment: Where is your quote from? Please don't forget to provide source attribution when quoting!

Comment: @Supersharp Yes, the spec says that "not" is a "functional pseudo-class", https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation

Answer (score 3):

Actually the reason is given in [Selector Level 4 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#data-model):

> The shadow host in a shadow tree is *featureless* and therefore cannot be matched by any pseudo-class except for `:host` [...].

It is illustrated in the [hyperlink](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#host-selector) in the example (and actually also the link you pointed in your comment to @Intervalia's answer).

Transposed to your use case:

`:focus-within` doesn't match the shadow host. So, `:host:focus-within` which is more specific, should/could not match anything (that would be contradictory to the CSS selection fundamental).

Hence the `:host()` function pseudo-class that will mimic the other selectors but won't break their logic.

Comment: Hello again! If `:host:focus-within`, "should/could not match anything " then why did `:host(:host:focus-within) div` work in my third example? How would we translate that selector to an English language description to explain what it's selecting for?